# match two numbers in MS-Excel

Tags: excel, match

how I make formula in MS_excel
 match two values 101 and 111 in one range a1 to a20

```
match (101 & 111 ,a1:a20,0)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data that would populate A1:A20 and what you would expect to return.

Comment: 301
111
108
201
601
478

Comment: A1 to A20 only one value 101 or 111 ,not both them

Comment: OK, then use the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) to pass the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to a second value. e.g. `=IFERROR(MATCH(101, A1:A20, 0), MATCH(111, A1:A20, 0))`

Comment: Thanks Mr @Jeeped to answer me

Comment: as array formula with CSE you can use `=MIN(IFERROR(MATCH({101,111},A1:A20,0),FALSE))` to get the first item of 101 or 111 (whatever comes first) or get 0 if none exist... or do it with a list of numbers like `=MIN(IFERROR(MATCH(B1:B5,A1:A20,0),FALSE))`